# Laptop is treating speakers as headphones

Tags: audio, speakers, headphones

Up until recently, whenever I plugged in my headphones, the sound would switch over from my laptop's speakers to my headphones. Now, plugging in headphones only results in the speakers becoming lower, which makes me think the speakers are being treated as headphones.

Any solutions? I have not changed any drivers recently, or software for that matter.

Comment: And do your headphones still work when you plug them in? Have you tried with a different pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution (rather simple, really). Somehow, I had set Independent Dual Headphones as my default playback device. Going to the Sound control panel, I just had to set Speakers and Dual Headphones as the default device, and everything is working again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the driver for your sound card so you can change to input / output devices. I can put the example of my realtek driver :

[image]